# What is the purpose of the -m switch?

Tags: python, command-line, module, package

Could you explain to me what the difference is between calling

```
python -m mymod1 mymod2.py args
```

and

```
python mymod1.py mymod2.py args
```

It seems in both cases `mymod1.py` is called and `sys.argv` is

```
['mymod1.py', 'mymod2.py', 'args']
```

So what is the `-m` switch for?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but `-m` seems to search for `mymod1` in the default library path. Example: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` works, whereas `python SimpleHTTPServer` fails with `can't open file 'SimpleHTTPServer': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Comment: I actually found the answer here clearer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319694/what-does-it-mean-to-run-library-module-as-a-script-with-the-m-option

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The first line of the `Rationale` section of [PEP 338](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) says:

> Python 2.4 adds the command line switch -m to allow modules to be located using the Python module namespace for execution as scripts. The motivating examples were standard library modules such as pdb and profile, and the Python 2.4 implementation is fine for this limited purpose.

So you can specify any module in Python's search path this way, not just files in the current directory. You're correct that `python mymod1.py mymod2.py args` has exactly the same effect. The first line of the `Scope of this proposal` section states:

> In Python 2.4, a module located using -m is executed just as if its filename had been provided on the command line.

With `-m` more is possible, like working with modules which are part of a package, etc. That's what the rest of PEP 338 is about. Read it for more info.

Comment: My favorite usage of `-m` is `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. Really handy when I need to share some files without using a usb flash drive.

Comment: @arifwn Running Python3 requires a slight update as `python -m http.server` and this is still awesome!

Comment: TL;DR: 1) You can run `python -m package.subpackage.module` and the normal resolving machinery will be used, you don't have to point out the exact `.py` file. 2) It is possible to do relative imports from the module that is run, without any workarounds, because its package will be loaded along the way. 3) Absolute imports will be based on your current directory, not the directory where the `.py` file is (`''` is at the head of `sys.path`, rather than `/path/to/my`, if the script is at `/path/to/my/script.py`).

Comment: What this answer doesn't make it clear is **this only works on the subset of modules that are executable** i.e. have a `__main__.py` file. Most don't and will break e.g. `python -m sys 'print(sys.version)'` fails with `python: No code object available for sys`. Suggest you make that clear in the answer.

Answer (score 250):

Despite this question having been asked and answered several times (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52441280/1066291), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22241420/1066291), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50821312/1066291), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46319694/1066291)), in my opinion no existing answer fully or concisely captures all the implications of the `-m` flag. Therefore, the following will attempt to improve on what has come before.

## Introduction (TLDR)

The `-m` flag does a lot of things, not all of which will be needed all the time. In short, it can be used to: (1) execute python code from the command line via modulename rather than filename (2) add a directory to `sys.path` for use in `import` resolution and (3) execute python code that contains relative imports from the command line.

## Preliminaries

To explain the `-m` flag we first need to explain a little terminology.

Python's primary organizational unit is known as a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module). Modules come in one of two flavors: code modules and package modules. A code module is any file that contains python executable code. A package module is any directory that contains other modules (either code modules or package modules). The most common type of code module is a `*.py` file while the most common type of package module is a directory containing an `__init__.py` file.

Python allows modules to be uniquely identified in two ways: modulename and filename. In general, modules are identified by modulename in Python code (e.g., `import <modulename>`) and by filename on the command line (e.g., `python <filename>`). All Python interpreters are able to convert modulenames to filenames by following the same few, well-defined rules. These rules hinge on the `sys.path` variable. By altering this variable one can change how Python resolves modulenames into filenames (for more on how this is done see [PEP 302](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/)).

All modules (both code and package) can be executed (i.e., code associated with the module will be evaluated by the Python interpreter). Depending on the execution method (and module type) what code gets evaluated, and when, can change quite a bit. For example, if one executes a package module via `python <filename>` then `<filename>/__main__.py` will be executed. On the other hand, if one executes that same package module via `import <modulename>` then only the package's `__init__.py` will be executed.

## Historical Development of `-m`

The `-m` flag was first introduced in [Python 2.4.1](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4.1/notes/). Initially its only purpose was to provide an alternative means of identifying the python module to execute from the command line. That is, if we knew both the `<filename>` and `<modulename>` for a module then the following two commands were equivalent: `python <filename> <args>` and `python -m <modulename> <args>`. One constraint with this iteration, according to [PEP 338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/#current-behaviour), was that `-m` only worked with top level modulenames (i.e., modules that could be found directly on `sys.path` without any intervening package modules).

With the completion of [PEP 338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) the `-m` feature was extended to support `<modulename>` representations beyond the top level. This meant names such as `http.server` were now fully supported. This extension also meant that each parent package in modulename was now evaluated (i.e., all parent package `__init__.py` files were evaluated) in addition to the module referenced by the modulename itself.

The final major feature enhancement for `-m` came with [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/). With this upgrade `-m` gained the ability to support not only absolute imports but also explicit relative imports when executing modules. This was achieved by changing `-m` so that it set the `__package__` variable to the parent module of the given modulename (in addition to everything else it already did).

## Use Cases

There are two notable use cases for the `-m` flag:

1. To execute modules from the command line for which one may not know their filename. This use case takes advantage of the fact that the Python interpreter knows how to convert modulenames to filenames. This is particularly advantageous when one wants to run stdlib modules or 3rd-party module from the command line. For example, very few people know the filename for the `http.server` module but most people do know its modulename so we can execute it from the command line using `python -m http.server`.
2. To execute a local package containing absolute or relative imports without needing to install it. This use case is detailed in [PEP 338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/#import-statements-and-the-main-module) and leverages the fact that the current working directory is added to `sys.path` rather than the module's directory. This use case is very similar to using `pip install -e .` to install a package in develop/edit mode.

## Shortcomings

With all the enhancements made to `-m` over the years it still has one major shortcoming -- it can only execute modules written in Python (i.e., `*.py`). For example, if `-m` is used to execute a C compiled code module the following error will be produced, `No code object available for <modulename>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6165824/1066291) for more details).

## Detailed Comparisons

**Module execution via import statement (i.e., `import <modulename>`):**

- `sys.path` is *not* modified in any way
- `__name__` is set to the absolute form of `<modulename>`
- `__package__` is set to the immediate parent package in `<modulename>`
- `__init__.py` is evaluated for all packages (including its own for package modules)
- `__main__.py` is *not* evaluated for package modules; the code is evaluated for code modules

**Module execution via command line with filename (i.e., `python <filename>`):**

- `sys.path` is modified to include the final directory in `<filename>`
- `__name__` is set to `'__main__'`
- `__package__` is set to `None`
- `__init__.py` is not evaluated for any package (including its own for package modules)
- `__main__.py` is evaluated for package modules; the code is evaluated for code modules.

**Module execution via command line with modulename (i.e., `python -m <modulename>`):**

- `sys.path` is modified to include the current directory
- `__name__` is set to `'__main__'`
- `__package__` is set to the immediate parent package in `<modulename>`
- `__init__.py` is evaluated for all packages (including its own for package modules)
- `__main__.py` is evaluated for package modules; the code is evaluated for code modules

### Conclusion

The `-m` flag is, at its simplest, a means to execute python scripts from the command line by using modulenames rather than filenames. The real power of `-m`, however, is in its ability to combine the power of `import` statements (e.g., support for explicit relative imports and automatic package `__init__` evaluation) with the convenience of the command line.

Comment: Could you also add the use of invoking package using `python -m packagename` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53772635/1779091

Comment: @variable good idea, I added a "Use Case" section that includes that.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive presentation on the subject that I have read. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an opinion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63909243/2326961)?

Comment: I think this sentence should be modified:

*"For example, if one executes a package module via `python <filename>` then `<filename>/__init__.py` will be evaluated followed by `<filename>/__main__.py.`"*
 
 - Did you try to say <dirname>? If that's the case, only `<dirname>/__main__.py` would be executed.

Comment: @starriet Oh, you're right. I sure thought I'd tested that but when I just tried again it behaved like you said. Oh looks like I got it right at the end. I guess I didn't go back and fix it. And yeah, I'm using <filename> to generally mean any path (including directories).

Comment: Module execution via command line with filename (i.e., python <filename>): ```__package__ ``` is '' if a package module is run. ```Python foo``` where foo is a package

Comment: This is a wonderful answer!! I wish it had so many upvotes that anybody typing even amazon package gives this as the first search result. 

Maybe you would like to add a bit about where the module is executed from. you cover it implicitly by using the term parents package but, determining parent package is not that straightforward. For example: ```python -m package.foo``` vs ```python -m foo``` from within the package directory

Answer (score 38):

It's worth mentioning **this only works if the package has a file `__main__.py`** Otherwise, this package can not be executed directly.

```
python -m some_package some_arguments
```

The python interpreter will looking for a `__main__.py` file in the package path to execute. It's equivalent to:

```
python path_to_package/__main__.py somearguments
```

It will execute the content after:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: What about the package init file? In presence of the main file, will init also be invoked?

Comment: @variable Yes __init__.py will be invoked before __main__.py is invoked

Comment: this is not accurate. if you will try run directly the __main__ .py of a package it would not work as you would run the package with python -m flag

Answer (score 8):

I just want to mention one potentially confusing case.

Suppose you use `pip3` to install a package `foo`, which contains a `bar` module. So this means you can execute `python3 -m foo.bar` from any directory. On the other hand, you have a directory structure like this:

```
src
|
+-- foo
    |
    +-- __init__.py
    |
    +-- bar.py
```

You are at `src/`. When you run `python -m foo.bar`, you are running the `bar.py`, instead of the installed module. However, if you are calling `python -m foo.bar` from any other directory, you are using the installed module.

This behavior certainly doesn't happen if you are using `python` instead of `python -m`, and can be confusing for beginners. The reason is the order how Python searches for modules.

Answer (score 5):

In short, one of the best use case for 'python -m' switch is when you want to tell Python that you want to run a module instead of executing a .py file.

Consider this example: you have a Python script in a file named 'venv' (without '.py' file extension). If you issue this command:

```
python venv
```

then, Python will excute the 'venv' file in the current directory. However, if instead you want to create a new virtual environment using the 'python venv' module, you would run:

```
python -m venv
```

in which case, Python will run the 'venv' module, not the file 'venv'.

Another example, if you want to run Pyhton's built-in local http server and issue the command:

```
python http.server
```

you would get an error like:

```
python: can't open file '/home/user/http.server': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

That's because Python tried to execute a file called 'http.server' and didn't find it.
So instead, you want to issue the same command but with '-m' switch:

```
python -m http.server
```

so that Python knows you want the module 'http.server' not the file.

Comment: What is the difference between  "python -m pip install sphinx" and "python pip install sphinx"?

Answer (score 4):

Since this question comes up when you google `Use of "python -m"`, I just wanted to add a quick reference for those who like to modularize code without creating full [python packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) or [modifying](https://gist.github.com/TheProjectsGuy/a998c0a53313ee0bdc937018603d93a4) `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` every time.

### Setup

Let's setup the following file structure

```
.
├── f1
│   ├── f2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test2.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test1.py
└── test.py
```

Let the present path be `m1`.

### Using `python -m` instead of `python ./*`

1. Use `.` qualified *module* names for the files (because they're being treated as modules now). For example, to run the contents in `./f1/test1.py`, we do

   ```bash
   python -m f1.test1
   ```

   and not

   ```bash
   python ./f1/test1.py
   ```
2. When using the *module* method, the `sys.path` in `test1.py` (when that is run) is `m1`. When using the `./` (relative file) method, the path is `m1/f1`.

   So we can access all files *in* `m1` (and assume that it is a full python package) using `-m`. This is because the path to `m1` is stored (as `PYTHONPATH`).
3. If we want to run deeply nested "modules", we can still use `.` (just as we do in `import` statements).

   ```bash
   # This can be done
   python -m f1.f2.test2
   ```

   And in `test2.py`, we can do `from f1.test1 import do_something` without using any [path gimmicks](https://gist.github.com/TheProjectsGuy/a998c0a53313ee0bdc937018603d93a4) in it.
4. Every time we do module imports this way, the `__init__.py` is automatically called. This is true even when we're nesting.

   ```bash
   python -m f1.f2.test2
   ```

   When we do that, the `./f1/__init__.py` is called, followed by `./f1/f2/__init__.py`.