# Permission denied when installing Pylint on VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When trying to enable linting with Pylint, and format on save with autopep8, neither will install because of a permission denied error.

Pylint:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mccabe.py'
```

Autopep8:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pep8.py'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7
```

Comment: Doesn't this mess up the permissions with homebrew (for updates) or other system tools since the owner of this directory is `root`?

Answer (score 9):

You can press ⬆ (up arrow key) in the terminal tab after the install fails to return to the command that it ran. In this case:

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install pylint
```

Press fn+⬅ (left arrow key) to jump to the beginning of the line, then insert a 'sudo ' (no quotes, but including the trailing space) in front of the command, and press enter to re-run the command as root -- it should look like this:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python -m pip install pylint
```

You will be prompted for your password then the package will be installed without permissions errors.

Comment: Link to what -m does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch

Answer (score 0):

Use for Python V3+

```
sudo -H python -m pip install pylint
```

then simply check the version via

```
pylint --version
```

should output something like

```
pylint 2.6.2
astroid 2.4.2
Python 3.9.1 (default, Feb  1 2021, 12:12:57) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)]
```