# What does it mean to "run library module as a script" with the "-m" option?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python (and to programming as well) and, although well documented, I cannot understand what exactly means the -m directive (precisely in the creation of a virtual environment: `python3 -m venv my_env`.

As far as I can read from the documentation, it stands for "run library module as a script": it is in fact this concept that I cannot figure out and what is the difference in running the command without the `-m`.

Moreover, it this a characteristic of Python 3?

Comment: Documentation is your friend: https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

Comment: You've read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)? Just asking because you said it's well documented but didn't link to the "documentation".

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Python modules are just script files that are located in a place where Python can find them. As with all scripts, you can just run them directly if you know where they are, e.g. `python /path/to/module.py`.

Properly designed modules usually do nothing except set up stuff (e.g. functions and types you could import), but they usually won’t have any visible side effect. That’s why you can do `import sys` and nothing happens.

However, some modules may offer useful stuff when they are run from the command line. Examples for that include `venv` but also `http.server` or `idlelib`: All of those are regular modules that can be imported from other modules without side effects.

But when executed directly, they all do things (e.g. `venv` sets up a virtual environment, `http.server` runs a simple HTTP server, and `idlelib` runs IDLE). This is usually done with the following check:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Module is being executed directly, so do stuff here')
```

This is a special way of recognizing of a script/module is being executed directly, or whether it’s just being imported from some other module. You can learn more about the question [“What does `if __name__ == '__main__':` do?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/216074).

So, you can run a module directly using `python /path/to/module.py` as we established before. But this requires you to know the full path to the module. That’s where the `-m` option comes into play: For modules that can usually be imported just using `import modulename`, you can use `python -m modulename` to run that module directly. Just as if you typed the full path to it.

So for our above examples, we can just use `python -m venv`, `python -m http.server`. or `python -m idlelib`.

Comment: Other cool examle is `json.tool` for pretty-printing from the shell. `echo '{"1":"a","2":"b"}' | python -m json.tool`

Comment: Awesome answer. Just one addition: If it's a 'package'(a directory rather than a single .py file), `python -m modulename` works slightly different than `python /path/to/package`. The former executes both `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`, but the latter executes **only** `__main__.py`. [(more details)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923810/10027592)

Answer (score 0):

Say for example you have folder structure like this

```
|-HelloModule
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ hellomodule.py
```

To run the hellomodule.py as a module means the command will be:

> `python -m HelloModule.hellomodule`

You can run this command from anywhere, including outside of the HelloModule directory, as long as you have `pip install`d your project.

Comment: For me, this looks a bit like wrong if we accept that the only thing the -m flag does is just what was specified in the answer above. Importing a function have nothing to do with with the script as if it is run from it is root dir.

Comment: I dont see anything in this (unedited) answer about 'running from root dir'