# 'flask run' can't find code when run from source directory, while 'python -m flask run' succeeds

Tags: python, flask

This is not the same as "What is the purpose of the -m switch" as I'm talking about a function that runs independently (flask) and wanting to know why it works differently with -m.  The answers there do not resolve the question.

I have a flask app that I'm building.  It's set up with a subdirectory for the code, so

```
setup.py
gallery/
   __init.py__
   models.py
   view.py
```

When I run it using 'python -m flask run' it works.  When I run it just as 'flask run' it doesn't.  I haven't been able to find anyone who knows what the actual difference is between the two commands, so I'm kind of stuck.

Here's the output from 'flask run':

```
(venv)MacBook-Pro-4:Finished khunter$ export FLASK_APP=gallery
(venv)MacBook-Pro-4:Finished khunter$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: The file/path provided (gallery) does not appear to exist.  Please      
verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the 
extension is .py
```

Any thoughts about where the difference lies so I can use 'flask run' appropriately?

EDIT: It looks like I can get through this with pip install --editable to grab the setup.py I have there.

Comment: This might interest you. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319694/what-does-it-mean-to-run-library-module-as-a-script-with-the-m-option)

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  Flask is supposed to run as its own independent function - 'flask run' should work exactly like 'python -m flask run'

Comment: "just fails" means what? Throws an import error? Returns immediately with no output? Something else? Comparing the output of `python -c 'import flask; print(flask.__file__)'` and `command -v flask` at the shell may (or may not) be useful. Including the values of the environment variables `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`, likewise.

Comment: It fails with "cannot find gallery".  But gallery is set up fine, since it works with python -m.  There's probably an unreported error (flask tends towards those) but I have no visibility into it because all of the examples say "Doesn't run?  Do it with python -m to find out why!" - but it does not fail in the same way.

Comment: That error is *relevant*; it tells us very explicitly that you have a different `sys.path` between the two invocation methods, which wasn't clear before. [Edit] its exact text into the question.

Comment: (actually, if your shell is bash, `type flask` is a step up from `command -v flash`, as it'll describe any aliases or shell functions involved in invocation).

Comment: ...indeed, please consider all the above (`type flask`, `type python`, `declare -p PATH PYTHONPATH`) requests to add details to the question, as opposed to merely advice on debugging steps you might run yourself.

Comment: ...and btw, the "if app is not on PYTHONPATH" advice in the error message is not a bad place to start. Does running `PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH FLASK_APP=gallery flask run` change behavior? (When putting variable assignments at the front of a shell command they're both automatically exported and scoped only to that one command, so the intent is to run that as a single command).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't many differences. When you run `python -m flask run`, you are running [`flask/__main__.py`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/afb7e4ee5f6e9cb8a1a937458cb39ee312e172ae/flask/__main__.py).

While when you run `flask run`, you are running [`flask/cli.py`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/afb7e4ee5f6e9cb8a1a937458cb39ee312e172ae/flask/cli.py#L883).

As you can see, the first one is just an alias of the second one. Although it passes `as_module == True`. The reason why it need to be additionally processed is showed in comment. You can check it by yourself.

I believe your issue is caused by path problem. Double check if your path is correct.

Comment: What path?  And how can I check it?  With 'flask run' I don't get any useful output about *anything* (it just fails)

Comment: @KirstenJones Well, I think the comments of your question have clarified what I mean about path.