# python -m causes "Error while finding module specification for"

Tags: python

The doc [says](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html)

> Some Python modules are also useful as scripts. These can be invoked using python -m module [arg] ..., which executes the source file for module as if you had spelled out its full name on the command line

I wrote this code to help myself understand the `-m`

```
def print_hi(n=1):
    print('hi'*n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_hi(9)
```

I saved this as a file `aname.py`.

And then I ran this command, and get the expected result.

```
$ python aname.py 
hihihihihihihihihi
```

## question

When I execute the file as a module, this error shows up

```
$ python -m aname.py
/usr/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'aname.py' (AttributeError: module 'aname' has no attribute '__path__')
```

What causes this error? How to fix it?

Comment: [What does it mean to “run library module as a script” with the “-m” option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319694/what-does-it-mean-to-run-library-module-as-a-script-with-the-m-option) might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're supposed to use the m without the .py suffix, i.e.: `$ python -m aname`

From the man page:

```
       -m module-name
              Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as
              a script.
```

The m parameter is a module, similar to `import` or `from`.