# Portable way to import modules from parent directory in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I know this is a worn out topic but the import mechanism/s in python is still confusing the masses. What I want is the ability to import a custom module that is in a parent directory in a way that allows me to take a project to another environment and have all of the imports work.
For example a structure like this:

```
repo 
  |--- folder1
  |       |--- script1.py
  |--- folder2       
  |       |--- script2.py 
  |--- utils
          |--- some-util.py
```

How can I import from `some-util.py` in both `script1` and `script2`? The idea is that I could clone the repo into a remote host and run scripts from folders 1 and 2 that may have the shared dependency of `some-util.py` only I don't want to have to run anything before hand. I want to be able to:

connect to box

```
git clone repo
python repo/folder1/script1.py
```

contents of script1 and script2:

```
import some-util

<code>
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that occasionally the scripts need to be run from another directory like:
`/nas/some_folder/repo/folder1/script1.py args..`

Also, the box is limited to python 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to implement as your scripts as modules (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319694/what-does-it-mean-to-run-library-module-as-a-script-with-the-m-option) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch) for an overview of what the `python -m` switch means).

Here is a structure, also notice every directory contains an (empty file) named `__init__.py`:

```
repo/
|____utils/
| |____someutil.py
| |___ __init__.py
|___ __init__.py
|____folder1/
  |____script1.py
  |___ __init__.py
```

`utils.someutil` may contain something like this:

```py
def say_hello():
    return "Hello World."
```

And your `script1.py` may contain something like:

```py
from ..utils.someutil import say_hello

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(say_hello())
```

Then running the following:

```
python -m repo.folder1.script1
```

... produces:

```
Hello World.
```

Comment: Your answer works exactly as you posted. Thanks showing how to do that, however I forgot to mention (see edit) that I need to be able to run the scripts from anywhere on the linux server as well. Your answer only works if you are a level above the root (repo) dir. Otherwise you get:
`No module named <some parent directory>.repo.folder1`