# How to save data to remote mongoDB via ssh tunnel? (connection refused)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunnel, python-sacred

I have two computers: Ubuntu1 and Ubuntu2. 
Ubuntu1 runs MongoDB with database Sacred3. 
I want to connect from U2 to U1 via ssh and store there my experiment results.

What I tried and failed:
1. I installed mongo DB, created sacred3, I have ssh key to it. 
I edited `/etc/mongod.conf` adding:

`# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0`

Then I enabled port forwarding with

`ssh -fN  -i ~/.ssh/sacred_key-pair.pem -L 6666:localhost:27017 ubuntu@106.969.696.969` // (with proper ip)

so, as I undertstand, if I connect to my localhost:6666 it will be forwarded to 106.969.696.969:27017

So after that, I'm runnig an experiment with [Sacred framework](https://sacred.readthedocs.io/en/stable/observers.html):

python exp1.py -m localhost:6666:sacred3

and this should write experiment to remote DB, HOWEVER i I get:

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

which is driving me mad. please help!

#

below contents of exp1.py:

```
from sacred import Experiment
from sacred.observers import MongoObserver

ex = Experiment()
ex.observers.append(MongoObserver.create())

def compute():
    summ = layer1 - layer2
    return summ


@ex.config
def my_config():

    hp_list = [{"neurons" : [32,32] , "dropout": 1.0},
            {"neurons" : [32,32] , "dropout": 0.7},
            {"neurons" : [32,16] , "dropout": 0.9},
            {"neurons" : [24,16] , "dropout": 0.9},
            {"neurons" : [24,8] , "dropout":  0.9},
            {"neurons" : [16,8] , "dropout":  0.9},
            {"neurons" : [64,64] , "dropout": 0.9},
            {"neurons" : [64,64] , "dropout": 0.7},
            {"neurons" : [64,32] , "dropout": 0.9},
            {"neurons" : [64,32] , "dropout": 0.7},
            {"neurons" : [48,32] , "dropout": 0.9},
            {"neurons" : [48,32] , "dropout": 0.7},
            {"neurons" : [48,16] , "dropout": 0.9},
            {"neurons" : [48,16] , "dropout": 0.7},]

    n_epochs = 2 


@ex.capture
def training_loop(hp_list, n_epochs):
    for j in hp_list:
        print("Epoch: ", n_epochs)
#       layer1 = random.randint(18,68)
#       layer2 = random.randint(18,68)
#       layer3 = random.randint(18,68)
        layer1 = j["neurons"][0]
        layer2 = j["neurons"][1]
        dropout_ratio = j["dropout"]


        print("WHATS UUUUUP",j, layer1, layer2, dropout_ratio, sep="_")
        # vae_training_loop_NN_DO(i, layer1, layer2, dropout_ratio )


@ex.automain
def my_main():
    training_loop()
```

Comment: Looks like you're not passing the port to the script correctly and therefore connecting to localhost:27017 instead of localhost:6666

Comment: what do you mean? I run script with python exp1.py -m localhost:6666:sacred3

Comment: afaik the `-m` switch [isn't for passing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch) to a script.. Can we see the contents of your script?

Comment: I added contents of exp1.py just like it is here https://sacred.readthedocs.io/en/stable/observers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [supplied](https://sacred.readthedocs.io/en/stable/observers.html), it looks like you're creating two observers, or overriding the connection argument you passed with `-m`, with the `MongoObserver.create()`specified in the code which uses the default mongo host and port `localhost:27017`. You either supply the observer connection via the `-m` argument or in code, not both.

Try removing the `MongoObserver.create()` line altogether, or hardcoding the connection arguments: `MongoObserver(url='localhost:6666', db_name='sacred3')`

Also, it looks like your mongo host is [not liking the binding to localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/489192/ssh-tunnel-refusing-connections-with-channel-2-open-failed) so you should also replace `localhost` in your ssh command with `127.0.0.1` or `[::1]`, e.g `ssh -fN -i ~/.ssh/sacred_key-pair.pem -L 6666:127.0.0.1:27017 ubuntu@106.969.696.969` or `ssh -fN -i ~/.ssh/sacred_key-pair.pem -L 6666:[::1]:27017 ubuntu@106.969.696.969`

Comment: I removed line ex.observers.append(MongoObserver.create()) and now I'm getting this error: channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

Comment: Now it looks like your mongo host is [not liking the binding to localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/489192/ssh-tunnel-refusing-connections-with-channel-2-open-failed). Can you try replacing `localhost` in your ssh command with `127.0.0.1` or `[::1]`, e.g `ssh -fN  -i ~/.ssh/sacred_key-pair.pem -L 6666:127.0.0.1:27017 ubuntu@106.969.696.969`

Comment: Halleluyah, now it worked! Please add this comment to your answer so other people can see it all.

Comment: Done. Then you could also update your question with the second error so it shows up in search results for that error.