# Understanding the meaning of python -m in code

Tags: python-3.x

I see people run `python -m $SomeOtherStuff(e.g. train.py)`.
What does `-m` mean exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the -m switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch)

Comment: yes! Thank you for bringing it to my attention.