# what is the difference in package loading between python -m and python [file]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

I'm seeing different package handling behavior in python3 when I'm running something like `python -m moduala.test` and `python moduala/testa.py`. In the -m case imports for moduala.modualb.pkgx in testa.py work and in the other case they don't work.

```
python --version
# Python 3.6.9

mkdir -p testpyproj/pkga/pkgb
cd testpyproj/

touch pkga/__init__.py
touch pkga/pkgb/__init__.py

echo 'print("# python!")' >pkga/pkgb/modx.py
echo 'from pkga.pkgb import modx' > pkga/test.py

python -m pkga.test
# python!

python pkga/test.py 
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "pkga/test.py", line 1, in <module>
#     from pkga.pkgb import modx
# ImportError: No module named pkga.pkgb
```

From the man page I would expect these to be the same:

> ```
>   -m module-name
>          Searches sys.path for the named module and 
>          runs the corresponding .py file as a script.
> ```

What is the difference between python -m and python [file] for loading modules and handling packages?

Why does the python [file] not find pkga.pkgb?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch

Comment: Thanks @Armagon This comment on the suggested question is answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923810/223960

Comment: @Asocia Yes especially the answer by Mark Rucker

Answer (score 1):

When python runs a script from the command line, like:

```
$ python pkga/test.py
```

it *knows that it is running a relative script.* And so, as a result, it changes the value of `sys.path[0]` to be the **directory of the script.**

When python opens a module from the command line, it has to have a module search path (aka `sys.path`) in order to find the module. So it sets `sys.path[0]` to `""` (empty string) to indicate "the current directory". Then it searches through all the places indicated by `sys.path` trying to find the module name you have given.

The result of this is that in one case, your `sys.path[0]` is going to be `""` while in the other case it will be `/path/to/current/directory/pkga`. And then it cannot resolve `pkga.pkgb` when the search path starts from that location.

You can confirm this by adding:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

to the start of `pkga/test.py`, *before any other imports*. You will see the print output just before the module import exception.