# `pip install --upgrade pip` vs. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Tags: python, pip

What is the difference between:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

and

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

and why is `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` generally favoured?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch

Comment: Such questions are not encouraged on stackoverflow. You shoud do your own research on such subjective questions.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @JimitVaghela: It's not subjective; there are actual, objective reasons for choosing one over the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is between `pip` and `python -m pip`; the rest of the command doesn't matter. The reason to prefer the latter is that you're ensuring that the `python` you normally use is the one which will provide the `pip` module you invoke. Otherwise, there is a risk that the `pip` executable found in your `PATH` is from an unrelated or out of date Python installation; it might install packages, but your regular `python` invocation won't find them (because they're installed for a non-default Python).

On Windows, the distinction is even more important, as `pip.exe` can't be replaced while it's executing, so executing `pip` via the module with `-m` makes it possible to upgrade it in-place (typically, on Windows, you'd use [the `py.exe` launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), as `py -3 -mpip`, changing `-3` as desired to invoke a specific version of Python for which you wish to perform the upgrade)

You can also modify the second command to invoke specific Python executable names (`python2.7` vs. `python3.8`), or even absolute paths if you might have versions with the same name installed in multiple places.

Comment: It's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The first one

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

is to invoke `pip` as a command. The actual python interpretor called is not explicit. The second one is calling the python interpretor explicitly, so you know which one is called.

There should be no difference, as the `__main__.py` in the module and the `pip` script are both point to the same entry point, unless in the case that the default python is different from the one used by the pip script

Comment: This matters a great deal with multiple versions of python installed

Answer (score -1):

If i am correct, `pip install --upgrade pip` and `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` are the same unless you specify the pip or python version.
The latter is preferred because it attempts to upgrade the pip associated with the specified python version (e.g. python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip) even if the main python version is different (python command may refer to any python version).