# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to upgrade my pip and other libraries but this error kept appearing. What is this about? I'm thinking that I might be in the wrong directory, but I tried running it on Anaconda directory and still the same error keep showing.

How do I solve this? What directory should I be in?

```
(base) C:\Users\BINTANG>pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "f:\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "F:\anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

**EDIT**

Tried this already:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this not just a missing path in the `PATH` Environment Variable? Your OS does not know the `pip` command: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`. Therefore, either add the pip path to your `PATH` environment variable, or try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` instead. If `python` is in your Environment Variable, it will know `pip`. See also [`pip install --upgrade pip` vs. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459011/pip-install-upgrade-pip-vs-python-m-pip-install-upgrade-pip).

If even `python` is not known, you need to add `python` to your PATH environment variable or write down the whole `filepath/to/the/python.exe` instead of just "python".

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that something went wrong in installation process after deleting pip as the command was upgrading pip.

Typing this command
`python -m ensurepip --upgrade`
might restore the pip and upgrade it.

Comment: After going for that, the error message becomes: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'```

Comment: I don't know if this information is useful or not, but if I look to my Anaconda Navigator, the pip is still there.

Comment: I add another edit for the steps you given me