# On Python I cannot install beautifulsoup 4 4.9.3 using pip install beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I'm on a mac and the terminal is giving me a hard time.
`computer@computer ~ % pip install beautifulsoup4 zsh: command not found: pip`

I tried using `computer@computer ~ % pip3 install beautifulsoup4`, but it is an older 2.3 version of beautifulsoup4. Help me install pip and ultimately install beautifulsoup4.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538152/python-pip-installation-on-mac-is-not-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pip installation on Mac is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538152/python-pip-installation-on-mac-is-not-working)

Comment: I tried all the method described above, but I am only able to install python 2.7 version of pip, not the current 3.9.1

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and the message you get. Maybe to a new question.