# Mac M2 - Conda can't find python pip installations ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

On my new M2 Mac, I am having a tough time setting up my environment.

Within Conda,

```
which -a python
python: aliased to usr/bin/python3
opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/venv/bin/python

which -a pip
/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/venv/bin/pip
```

None of my pip installed modules in my env (conda activate venv) are accessible within python

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use `python3 -m pip` where python is from your conda

Comment: I get ```Usage: /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/venv/bin/python3```

Comment: Should this help?
[Python pip installation on Mac is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538152/python-pip-installation-on-mac-is-not-working)

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem but it looks like your question has several significant copy/paste errors. For example, `python: aliased to usr/bin/python3`. Where is the leading slash? Those sorts of errors make it less likely anyone will take the time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling `python` and `pip` from within `conda`, and reinstalling them again fixed the problem