# Module not found and __main__ is not a package in python import

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror, relative-import

I have following struct of the folder for my python code and I am using Python3.

```
python_lib/
      model_driver/
         __init__.py
         globals.py
         sb_driver.py
         test_driver.py
```

In test_driver.py, I have imported the modules as it is give below

```
from .sb_driver import*
from .globals import *
```

When I import sb_friver.py in test_driver.py then I have following error comes up.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.sb_driver'; '__main__'is not a package
```

I have even tried without '.' in front of module.But I have had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Run the module from inside the model_driver folder using [the -m switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923810/281545)

```
$ cd python_lib
$ python -m model_driver.test_driver
```

Using the -m switch `model_driver` will be registered as a package and relative imports will work. Using the m switch and running from the parent folder of the package is the correct way of running your srcipts - for details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64005448/281545)