# How to set up VS Code for imported modules to work in both debug and test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up a workspace in VS Code and I want to be able to run it in venv.

```
root
- app
-/- modules
-/-/- __init__.py
-/-/- myModule.py
-/-/- myModule2.py
-/- __init__.py
-/- myApp.py
- test
-/- myTest.py
- venv
```

myApp.py

```
import random
import numpy as np

import modules.myModule as mm

x = mm.main()
```

myModule.py

```
from app.modules import myModule2

def main():
    x = myModule2()
    return x
```

myTest.py

```
import unittest
from app.modules.myModule import main

class Test_Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        x = main()
        assertEqual(x, 'foobar', 'not equal')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The issue I'm having is that my own modules can either be run in debug or in test (as unit test) but the same set up can not run for both. When I have `from app.modules import myModule2` I can run test but not debug and when I have `from modules import myModule2` I can run debug but not test.

my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

my setting.json

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./test",
        "-p",
        "*test.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./app"
    ]
}
```

How do I set up my workspace to be able to run both?

I run debug on the file myApp.py, and I run the test from test explorer.

The error I get when running debug is:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'app'
```

The exception is caught in the file myModule.py in line `from app.modules import myModule2`.

Comment: I am using the VSC debug from the sidebar. The debug file is launch.json

Comment: Does `"program": "${file}",` → `"module": "app.myApp",` fit your use case?

Comment: @aaron yes that worked but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with running the test by executing `python test/myTest.py` is, that the `app` folder is not on the python path. The `unittest` module, if launched via its CLI takes care of this automatically if the folder structure is setup accordingly. Detailed information can be found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

Long story short:

1. Add an empty `__init__.py` file to your /test folder
2. Run `python -m unittest test/myTest.py`

To run *all* tests that are contained in multiple files named `test/*test.py`, use the `discover` option of the unittest package with matching arguments:

`python -m unittest discover -s "test/" -p "*test.py"`

I set up a VSC project matching the files you described, added the file `test/__init__.py` and created a virtual environment python venv.

The above option of running tests, I can achieve by adding following configurations to the launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: run single test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "unittest",
            "args": [
                "test/my_test.py"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: run all tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "unittest",
            "args": [
                "discover",
                "-s",
                "./test",
                "-p",
                "*test.py"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

which worked with debug enabled. I didn't create a setting.json file, so the python.unittest settings were set to default values.

Answer (score 1):

Change `"program": "${file}"` to `"module": "app.myApp"`.

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
//          "program": "${file}",  // Change this
            "module": "app.myApp", // to this
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, the difference is that:

- With `"program"`, Python adds the final directory in `${file}` (i.e. `/path/to/root/app/`) to `sys.path` (so you can only import `modules`).
- With `"module"` or `-m`, Python adds the current directory (i.e. `/path/to/root/`) to `sys.path` (so you can import `app`) and imports the containing package of `app.myApp` (i.e. `app`).

For detailed comparisons, see [What is the purpose of the -m switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7610001/8601760) (Ctrl+F "Detailed Comparisons").

References:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_module
- https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/#proposed-semantics

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from a total waste of time problem with Python, unit testing, unit tests discovery and Visual Studio Code.