# Why I'm Getting error when I run workon command?

Tags: python, django

I'm Totally newb in Django!
everytime I get error when I run workon

even I install `workon` module but it didn't help me
whenever I run

```sh
python -m workon test
```

it shows me

```sh
No module named workon!
```

any solution?
best regards
Nafiz

Comment: Please add some output and detailed error description - you might want to post your console output and additional information regarding your installation. Do you use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) or your  used OS/Python/Django version.

Answer (score 0):

You usually run workon to initialize a virtualenv. When you run `python -m workon` you are trying to run a python file inside a module or something similar (here is a good explanation on what it means: [What is the purpose of the -m switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch)). In your case, you are trying to run a python script/module named workon, which does not exist. If you are using virtualenvwrapper, you need to run `workon name_of_your_virtualenv` to initialize it, and then you will be able to run your python code if needed.

Next time please post your console output so we can help you better.