# Separate script's functions into modules, callable by 2 separate mains

Tags: python, import, module, project

I have a single script that:

0. imports 2 sets of data: df_height['user', 'height'], df_age['user', 'age']
1. clean the data
2. analyse the data: i) sum(height), ii) mean(age), iii) sum(height) * mean(age)
3. display the data.

I want to:

- Separate the functions out into modules
- divide the different analysis into their own 'main'
- For each analysis, divide into i) import and clean, ii) process iii) display

---

**Here is the complete script** (in the comments with #-> I indicate in what folder the function will be moved to):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#1. functions for import data #-> These functions into src/import_data/import_data.py
def get_data_age():  
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "user_id":     ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
        "age":         [10,  20,  30, "55", 50], 
    })
    return df

def get_data_height(): 
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "user_id":     ['5', '7', '12', '5'], 
        "height":      [160, 170, 180, 'replace_this_with_190']
    })
    return df

 #2. functions for cleaning data #-> These functions into src/clean_data/clean_data.py
def clean_age (df): 
    df['age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['age'])
    return df 

def clean_height (df): 
    df['height'] = df['height'].replace("replace_this_with_190", 200)
    return df 

 #3. functions for processing data #-> These functions into src/alghorithms/calculations.py
def alghorithm_age (df):
    return df['age'].mean()

def alghorithm_height (df):
    return df['height'].sum()

 #4. functions in common (display data) #-> This functions into src/display_data/display_data.py
def common_function_display_data (data): 
    print (data)

 #5. function that combines data from alghorithm_height and alghorithm_age #-> This functions into src/alghorithms/calculations.py
def product_age_mean_and_height_sum(mean_age, sum_height): 
    return mean_age * sum_height


#main 1 (age)
df_age = get_data_age()    # -> this step into file main_age/00_import_and_clean_age.py
df_age_clean = clean_age(df_age)  # -> this step into file main_age/00_import_and_clean_age.py
age_mean = alghorithm_age(df_age_clean) # -> this step into main_age/file 01_process_age.py
common_function_display_data(age_mean)# -> this step into main_age/file 02_display_age.py

#main 2 (height)
df_height = get_data_height()# -> this step into file main_height/00_import_and_clean_height.py
df_height_clean = clean_height(df_height)# -> this step into file main_height/00_import_and_clean_height.py
height_sum = alghorithm_height(df_height_clean)# -> this step into main_height/file 01_process_height.py
common_function_display_data(height_sum)# -> this step into file main_height/02_display_height.py

#main 3 (combined)
age_mean_height_sum_product = product_age_mean_and_height_sum(age_mean, height_sum) # -> this step into file main_display_combined/display_combined.py
common_function_display_data(age_mean_height_sum_product)# -> this step into file main_height/02_display_height.py
```

**Here is the final project structure I had in mind**.

[github repo with example](https://github.com/leodtprojectsd/stack_two_mains)

[image: project structure]

### [image: Data flow]

**Problem**
However when i structure the project as above, I am unable to import modules into the main scripts. I believe this is because they are on parallel levels.
getting the following error:

```py
# EXAMPLE for file main_one_age/00_import_and_clean_age.py
---
from ..import_data.import_data import get_data_age
from ..clean_data.clean_data import clean_age

df_age = get_data_age()    # -> this step into file main_age/00_import_and_clean_age.py
df_age_clean = clean_age(df_age)  # -> this step into file main_age/00_import_and_clean_age.py

---
OUT:
    from ..import_data.import_data import get_data_age
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
PS C:\Users\leodt\LH_REPOS\src\src>
```

---

**QUESTIONS**

**Q:** How can I separate the script into modules/main into a common structure?

The current solution doesn't allow me to:

- place a main within a subfolder eg: main_one_age/main_here.py
  With this structure the code wont work
- run files like `import_and_clean_age_00.py` as main, if I do this i get the error:

```py
ef display_data_main_one(age_mean):
    return display_data.common_function_display_data(age_mean)
     
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    display_data("path to age mean")
    
 OUT: 
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'display_data'
```

Q: can you provide a soltion that re-writes "path_for_data_etc.py" into a standard form? and also add all the setup.py/ pyproject.toml etc that is needed for this to be considered a "completed" project?

Basically looking for a standard solution that I can then use as a template for my real projects.

Comment: For now i am just running the scrips with the "play" button in Vs code. Any solution that works that you can suggest is ok

Comment: mucking around with `sys.path` is absolutely the wrong way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. How to separate the script into modules/main?

The structure shown in the question is appropriate.

The proper way to run each script is from the `src/` directory, using the `-m` option:

```bash
python -m main_one_age.main_one_age_00_and_01_and_02
python -m main_one_age.import_and_clean_age_00
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m
- [What is the purpose of the -m switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7610001/8601760)

### 1.1. How to support running the files directly?

(e.g. with the "play" button in VS Code)

You would need this boilerplate at the top of each of those files:

```py
if __package__ is None:
    from pathlib import Path, sys
    sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent))
```

### 1.2. How to name main files?

Name main files as __main__.py, e.g. main_display_combined/__main__.py.
Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#main-py-in-python-packages

If you want to directly run a file named after its package and importing from its package,
i.e. main_display_combined/main_display_combined.py doing
`from main_display_combined import display_combined`,
you would need:

```py
if __package__ is None:
    from pathlib import Path, sys
    sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent))
    if str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent) in sys.path:
        sys.path.remove(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent))
```

## 2. How to rewrite path_for_data_etc.py into a standard form?

The Pythonic way would be:

```py
from pathlib import Path

ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

RAW_DATA_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "data" / "raw_data"
age_raw_data_path = RAW_DATA_DIR / "raw_age_data.csv"
height_raw_data_path = RAW_DATA_DIR / "raw_height_data.csv"

CLEAN_DATA_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "data" / "cleaned_data"
age_clean_data_path = CLEAN_DATA_DIR / "clean_age_data.csv"
height_clean_data_path = CLEAN_DATA_DIR / "clean_height_data.csv"
```

## 3. setup.py/pyproject.toml for this to be considered a "completed" project?

You just need a requirements.txt:

```
pandas
```

To install the requirements:

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I suggest `python -m venv`. Yes, include a readme and license. I would further suggest to nest all the Python modules in a `myproject/` folder (name it according to your project, some prefer `src/` especially for other programming languages).

Comment: "You just need a requirements.txt:" no. Using a `setup.py` and `pyproject.toml` is the correct way to make your project a installable

Comment: "You would need this boilerplate at the top of each of those files" *no*. You should properly package and install your project, not mucking around with `sys.path`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 1) This is an application, not a library. 2) How else can the file be run directly? Did you read the question and the rest of the answer?