# How to import module using path related to working directory in a python project that managed by poetry?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging, python-poetry

I'm using poetry to manage my python project, here's the project:

```
my_project/
├── pyproject.toml
├── module.py
└── scripts/
    └── main.py
```

And I want to know how to import function from `module.py` into `my_scripts/main.py` correctly.

My pyproject.toml:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "my_project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I have tried this:

```py
# In my_scripts/main.py

from module import my_function
```

And run these commands:

```bash
poetry install
poetry shell
python my_scripts/main.py
```

then got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'
```

I also have put a `__init__.py` under `my_project/` but didn't work out.

Comment: How do you run your `scripts/main.py` script? Which command do you use? You should edit your question to show the command.

Comment: By chance does it work with `python -m scripts.main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What made it work for me is to create a folder in your root with the same name of the package in the `pyproject.toml` file.
If you don't do this, poetry will not find your project and will not install it in editable mode.

You also need to let Python know that a folder is a package or sub-package by placing an `__init__.py` file in it.

```
my_project/
├─ pyproject.toml
├─ my_project/
   ├─ __init__.py
   ├─ module.py
   ├─ scripts/
      ├─ __init__.py
      ├─ main.py
```

When you initialize the folder you should see that the project is installed.

```bash
...> poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Installing the current project: my_project (0.1.0)
```

Last thing, you need to change the import in `main.py`.

```
# main.py

from my_project.module import my_function

print("my_function imported")
```

You can now activate the virtual environment (if it's not already active) and run your script.

```bash
...> poetry shell
Spawning shell within: C:\...\my_project\.venv
...
...> python my_project\scripts\main.py
my_function imported
```

### PS

As @sinoroc pointed out in the comments, it is possible (and preferable according to him) to run the module with `python -m my_project.scripts.main`.

I am new to the topic, but according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923810/12040751):

> __package__ is set to the immediate parent package in <modulename> [when running python via command line with the `-m` option]

This means that relative imports like the following magically work.

```
# main.py

from ..module import my_function

# ..module tells python to look in the parent directory for module.py

print("my_function imported")
```

```bash
...> python -m my_project.scripts.main
my_function imported
...> python my_project\scripts\main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Yes, seems like that could be one way to fix this. But you have to use `python -m myproject.scripts.main`.

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc, that's interesting. Could you elaborate on the difference? Feel free to edit the answer directly.

Comment: I do not know the details, it is a matter of `sys.path` I think. What I have read many times is that if the thing that Python should run is part of a package (there is a `__init__.py`), then it should preferrably be run with `python -m` and dotted notation. -- See the [references on this page](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/python_imports.html) but I admit it is not straightforward, I should try to find a better reference. -- Maybe there are better explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7610001

Comment: @edd313 @sinoroc Thank you guys for solutions. I found a simple way that I don't need to create a subdirectory or any `__init__.py` file. Just submitted my answer and I wanna know if there is any drawback of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by adding this line to the `pyproject.toml` under the `[tool.poetry]` section:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
# ...other fields
packages = [{ include = "**/*" }]
```

No `__init__.py` is needed. Just run:

```bash
poetry install
poetry shell
python scripts/main.py
```

Comment: Hi @Matt Peng, I am not sure about the drawbacks. My only comment is that this solution is not very common. Check out the default folder structure that you get with the [`poetry new`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli#new) command, for example. Or have a look on GitHub at the repositories of the packages that you use. They probably have no modules in the root folder, rather all the code is in `src/` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Additional packages can also be specified with `include` in your pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
# ...
packages = [
    { include = "my_package" },
    { include = "extra_package/**/*.py" },
]
```

Ref: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages