# Setuptools and pyproject.toml not recognizing location of package

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I'm attempting to package my code (in the hopes of pushing to distribution in the future) using the PEP recommended Setuptools package. It recommends using a pyproject.toml file according to the specific structure of the package, as seen below.

```
project_root
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── VulcanSportsCLIenv
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── pyproject.toml
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   └── VulcanSports
│       ├── VulcanSports_CLI.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── __main__.py
└── tests
    └── __init__.py
```

```
#pyproject.toml

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=67.0", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "VulcanSports"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
    {name = "Abe Mankavil", email = "abe.m.mankavil@gmail.com"},
]
description = "Command line interface for quick access to sports scores and odds"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 1 - Planning",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)"
]
dependencies = [
    "requests"
]
keywords = ['Vulcan','Sports']

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
#include = ["VulcanSports/*.py"]  
exclude = ["/VulcanSportsCLIenv"]
namespaces = false
```

The only thing I want to be packaged and distributed is the contents of the src file. After running the command `python -m pip install .` in the  `project_root` directory, where the pyproject.toml file exists, the build works but when running `python VulcanSports` outside the directory it cannot find the package and returns the error:

```
/Users/abemankavil/Desktop/VulcanSportsProject/VulcanSports-CLI/VulcanSportsCLIenv/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/abemankavil/Desktop/VulcanSportsProject/VulcanSports-CLI/VulcanSports': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can't seem to figure out why the package can't be found even though it appears under `pip list`. Would this be a problem with my directory structure or a problem with the pyproject.toml file?

Comment: The command you need is `python -m VulcanSports`. The `-m` is important: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7610001 -- Then once, this works, you might want to look at adding a `scripts` "[entry point](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#entry-points)" into `pyproject.toml` so that you can make a command `VulcanSports` available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you need is `python -m VulcanSports`. The `-m` is important: [What is the purpose of the -m switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7610001)

This will instruct the Python interpreter to look for the `VulcanSports.__main__` module (`VulcanSports/__main__.py`) and run it.

Then once, this works as expected, you might want to look at adding a `scripts` "[entry point](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#entry-points)" into `pyproject.toml` so that you can make a command `VulcanSports` available.