# How do code modules and package modules change in a conda environment?

Tags: python

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62923810/14773537) stackoverflow post explains the difference between running files with `import <modulename>`, `python <filename>`, and `python -m <modulename>`:

```
Module execution via import statement (i.e., import <modulename>):

sys.path is not modified in any way
__name__ is set to the absolute form of <modulename>
__package__ is set to the immediate parent package in <modulename>
__init__.py is evaluated for all packages (including its own for package modules)
__main__.py is not evaluated for package modules; the code is evaluated for code modules
Module execution via command line with filename (i.e., python <filename>):

sys.path is modified to include the final directory in <filename>
__name__ is set to '__main__'
__package__ is set to None
__init__.py is not evaluated for any package (including its own for package modules)
__main__.py is evaluated for package modules; the code is evaluated for code modules.
Module execution via command line with modulename (i.e., python -m <modulename>):

sys.path is modified to include the current directory
__name__ is set to '__main__'
__package__ is set to the immediate parent package in <modulename>
__init__.py is evaluated for all packages (including its own for package modules)
__main__.py is evaluated for package modules; the code is evaluated for code modules
```

However, I was curious how the `__name__`, `__package__`, `__init__.py`, and `__main__.py` change when running these commands are run in a conda environment?