# When to put a dot in relative imports? And what does the m-switch have to do with it?

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

I have a simple example project with these files:

```
folder
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    foobar.py
    script.py
```

In *foobar.py* the function `foo` is imported with `from .foo import foo`.
(It is then used in the function `foobar`).
In *script.py* the function `foobar` is imported with `from .foobar import foobar`.
(It is then executed.)

But putting the dots in the import statement is not always the right choice.
Depending on how the script is run, their presence can cause:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
Or their absence can cause:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foobar'`

The code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/entenschule/examples_py/tree/main/a001_misc/b004_relative_import). (There is also [the same with absolute paths](https://github.com/entenschule/examples_py/tree/main/a001_misc/b005_absolute_import).)

### with dots

This works for the two usecases that I need:

- run script using the [m-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001): `python -m project.folder.script`
- import `foobar` in the Python console: `from project.folder.foobar import foobar`

This screenshot shows how running the script works with and fails without the m-switch:

[image: overview with dots]

### without dots

Gladly there is no need to run the script without the m-switch.
(Although it would be nice, because the IDE has a button for that.)

This screenshot shows how running the script fails with and works without the m-switch:

[image]

### paths in detail

It seems worthwhile to take a closer look at `__name__` and `__file__` in all cases.
`__name__` of _script.py is always the string `'__main__'`.

[image]

### conclusion

Apparently for me this just boils down to having to use the dot and the m-switch.
(This is just mildly annoying, because my IDE does not have auto-completion for it.)

But I would still like to understand, why there are these two ways of doing essentially the same thing.
People often say, that the dot is for going up a directory (like `../` in HTML and PHP).
But there is something wrong with that, because the location is the same in both cases.
(We just talk about neighboring files in the same folder.)

This must be far from the first question about this topic.
I hope it is clear enough to compensate for that redundancy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: If you want to understand relative imports, you have to stop thinking in terms of folders and files and start thinking in terms of packages and modules.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain why the dot is useful and when its used.

1. The dot is really useful when you are creating more complex projects (like a website using Django or flask).
2. The simplest way to I would explain the dot in front of imports is that it basically adds the file directory into your codes import directories, let me explain.

your current directory when you are importing through `script.py` is: `folder`.

**Why without dot it works:** If you don't have the dot in front of your import, you are basically telling Python to import `foo.py` from the same directory as your `script.py`

**Why using dot it throws an error:**
Because you don't use a `main.py` to run your code (the main file would be outside of your folder but in the same directory). Python considers your script.py as your `__main__`, This means that you cannot use the dot in imports that are in your `script.py`. This is because you haven't told Python which is the file/folder from which to import foobar.

If you would have a `main.py`, when importing the line `from .foobar import foobar` you are basically writing the line: `from folder.foobar import foobar`. Which would be correct.

**Note**: (This would require you to write `import folder` inside your `main.py`, and write `from . import script` inside your `__init__.py`)

for your code, don't use the dot in front of imports and don't use the m-switch.

I suggest that you could make a `main.py` in the same directory as your `folder`, this would make it possible for you to create a more complex script without a big headache later on. (In this case you have to add the dot in all of your code inside the `folder`)

Comment: I meant main.py as in the file that you will be using to run the script, you can name it whatever you want I just used main.py. 
Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: It may take a while until I wrap my mind around this. :D Note, that there are two requirements: I want to run the script, but I also want to import foobar in the console. I am not sure that would work without the dot.

Comment: In that case you should use the method i suggested with the main.py.

Comment: Gladly I don't have to solve a real problem here, as I see no downside to the m-switch. The aim is just to bring more light into this confusing topic. I have modified the code to print the `__name__` and `__file__` variables in all cases. Would you say, that something relevant can be deduced from them? Are there other variables, that might be useful?

Comment: The prints definitely bring clarity to how Python handles relative imports. In my opinion, the best way to become good at this is by exercise. By using breakpoints and reading error messages you can save the hassle of logging every action when you debug.