Python and pip misconfiguration leads to package installation errors
I'm facing an issue with Python and pip where packages are not being installed under the correct version of Python. I am using Python 3.9.6:
python3 -V
Python 3.9.6

The pip version
pip3 --version
pip 21.2.4 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)

The paths for pip3 and python3 are:
whereis pip3
pip3: /usr/bin/pip3

whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3

Despite this, when I try to install google-cloud-storage using pip3 install google-cloud-storage, the package seems to install under Python 3.8. I receive the following warning:
WARNING: Target directory /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.63.0.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.

I attempted to resolve this by creating a virtual environment with:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m venv venv
And installing the package within the virtual environment:
/Users/username/Desktop/project/venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage

However, this did not resolve the issue. When I run my script, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/project/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.cloud import storage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Additionally, google-cloud-storage does not appear in the output of pip list or pip3 list.
I installed Python 3.9 using Homebrew. I have deleted all Python versions from /usr/local/lib/. I don't have any other version of Python other than Python 3.9 currently installed.
Could there be an issue with how pip is linked to Python versions on my system? How can I ensure that pip3 installs packages under Python 3.9?
Any help would be appreciated!

create virtual env, activate it, do run python3 -m pip install google-cloud-storage and use this virtual env for project runing

type/whereis/which are wrong ways to get relations between python and pip. /usr/bin/pip3 could be run under /usr/bin/python3.8 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix), check head -1 /usr/bin/pip3) while your /usr/bin/python3 is Python 3.9. First compare python3 --version and pip3 --version. If you want to make sure you run pip under your destination python3 run python3 -m pip. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch

Please be reminded — scripts could be pip3, pip3.8 or pip3.9 but the module in -m is always pip — with different pythons: python -m pip, python3 -m pip, python3.9 -m pip, python3.9 -m pip.

@sahasrara62 yep, I tried that as well. The error persists.

@phd Thanks; I've updated the results for the pip3 --version to the original question. Unfortunately, running pip under the python3 destination didn't help either. The virtual environment didn't help here either.

@dand1 How did you run your script in virtual environment? Must be run under its Python /Users/username/Desktop/project/venv/bin/python3. Or activate the environment and run python and pip.

@phd yep, I run it through python main.py and python3 main.py
no luck.

@phd would you advise completely reinstalling the Python? If so, what would be the best way to accomplish that? Some obvious stuff like brew uninstall python didn't work for me.

@phd  I managed to solve by explicitly specifying the target directorypip3 install google-cloud-storage -t /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages `

@phd managed to find the roots.  For some reason under the pip config there was a setup applied to all Python projects on the system. global.target='/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
Run pip config unset global.target and things get back to normal

For some reason, under the pip config, there was an installation setup applied to all Python projects on the systems that  The target option overrides the default install location for Python packages
global.target='/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages'
Run pip config unset global.target, and things get back to normal

If you're using Visual Studio Code, you can change the Python interpreter using the option in the bottom toolbar. If the text editor isn't recognizing the correct interpreter, try adding or removing the appropriate python in the path variable of your device to fix the issue.
